# Trying to understand how to use _.reduce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, reduce

I'm trying to solve this question:
Use _.reduce to multiply all the values in an array.

Here's what I came up with:

```
var product = _.reduce([1, 2, 3], function(x, y){ return x * y; }, 0);
= 9
```

Is this close?  I don't feel like I'm fulling grasping reduce(). Please help.

Comment: The 3rd parameter is the starting value. In this case you want to use `1`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis actually he should simply omit the final "initial value" parameter altogether - the definition of `reduce` is that without an initial value it'll take the first array value as the "initial value" and then iterate from the second value onwards

Comment: @Alnitak Fair enough. However, the reason the code is not working is with the 3rd parameter set to `0`, it's effectively returning `0 * 1 * 2 * 3`.

Comment: I assume the `= 9` is a typo and you actually meant `= 0` ?

Comment: @Phylogenesis that's the root cause, but setting the value to `1` is not the correct fix, because it's mathematically incorrect to say that the product of an empty set is 1.  The product of any empty set is undefined.

Comment: I take that back - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Answer (score 1):

You should either omit the final `0` parameter from your call to `_.reduce`, or replace it with `1`, depending on the semantics you want to achieve if you were to supply an empty array.

Rather than think of variables `x` and `y` in the callback, consider them as `accumulator` and `current`.   In the first pass the "initial value" parameter is passed as `accumulator`, and in each subsequent pass the result of the previous pass is supplied as `accumulator`.

The `0` you erroneously supplied is passed as the first value of `accumulator`, and therefore every subsequent multiplication also results in `0`.

Fortunately, the specification for `reduce` says that if you omit that initial value parameter then it will take the first element of the supplied array to be in the initial value for `accumulator` and then only iterate from the second element onwards.

If you don't supply an initial value then the array *must* have at least one element in it.